# JAVA: Resizing Array lists , what happens to the old and temporary arrays that are created?

Tags: java, memory-management, arraylist, dynamic-arrays

I've been working on a class in Java for a data structures assignment where we manually implement an array list, here is the method I created in the class that increases the capacity of the array list:

```
public void increaseCapacity () {

    Object[] tmp = new Object[_maxItems*2];
    if (_listItems !=null) {
        System.arraycopy(_listItems, 0, tmp, 0, _maxItems);
        _maxItems = _listItems.length;
    }
    _listItems = tmp;

} // Increase size of list (doubles in size each time)
```

with `_listItem` being the object array that I add elements to / resize ect.. , I understand how using the temporary array can copying its contents back into `_listItem` increases size but what I don't understand is what happens to the original `_listItem` array that was of the smaller size.

When the `tmp` object array is copied into `_listItem` is new memory created for the variable `_listItem` and the `tmp` is copied into that? Or is the same memory used with extra space "appended" onto it when `tmp` is copied into `_listItem`? (I hope that reads well).

Essentially is the array `_listItem` a new variable when `tmp` is copied into it and if so how has its size increased without me explicitly doing so?

I feel this has something to do with the was Java manages memory but I can't wrap my head round it.

Comment: Arrays are contiguous in memory. When you create a new array object it must allocate a new contiguous block of memory to hold the new values in. When you assign your variable _listItem to the tmp array, your changing the memory address that _listItem points to. At that point the original value becomes subject to GC (assuming no other references exist to it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do:

```
Object[] tmp = new Object[_maxItems*2];
```

You are creating a new array of `Object` and a variable `tmp` that references it.

Later, when you do:

```
_listItems = tmp;
```

two things happen:

1. The array that was referenced by `_listItems` is not referenced by it anymore. If it is not referenced by another variable elsewhere, then it will be garbage collected later.
2. The array that is referenced by `tmp` is now also referenced by `_listItems`. No copy is performed.

Java has a Garbage Collector mechanism. Every variable (except the variables of integral types like `int`, `float`, etc.) actually hold references to objects. These objects can be arrays or other plain objects, like String. Everytime an object is not referenced by any variable, the Garbage Collector can free the memory that the object uses. It will not necessarily do so immediately for performance reason, it can wait for a time where some memory will be required to create another object.

Comment: Awesome!!!  I think the thing that cleared this up the most is realising the `_listItems = tmp` is actuall editing a reference to the new array of Objects

Answer (score 2):

Once reference is lost and you can not access it again GarbageCollector will free the memory and the old(smaller) array will be "destroyed".

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_(computer_science)

Answer (score 1):

Before

```
_listItems = tmp;
```

`_listItems` is referencing the old array object . After that line, it is referencing the object referenced by `tmp`.

Assuming your program has no other reachable reference to the old object, it will be garbage collected and the memory it was taking up released.